# Why does my TZ environment variable takes the wrong effect in puppeteer?

Tags: timezone, puppeteer

Through the [env-object](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.11.0&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions) for the method `launch`, we can set a TZ environment variable to affect the timezone of the browser.  This is confirmed by an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3325), where one explicitly mentions that.

I'm taking a screenshot of [this page](https://www.ymcatoledo.org/google-calendar/anthony-wayne-community-ymca/) which shows a Google calendar.  Setting puppeteer's TZ to US/Eastern yields times two hours later.  Setting TZ to Brazil/East yields the correct US/Eastern time.

**What am I missing here?**

The machine timezone is actually set to UTC:

```
$ date
Fri Nov 30 17:09:55 UTC 2018
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  I see you've been around for about 7 months now.  Unfortunately, your question doesn't meet the quality bar.  It needs to represent your complete problem, in a way that is fully understandable and/or reproducible from the question itself.  A link can support a question or answer, but can't stand alone.  Specifically here, you give a link to a page showing a calendar, but it's quite unclear what you are saying is wrong on that page.  Also it's possible that page may go away in the future and then this question will be impossible for others to interpret.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the purpose of StackOverflow is to provide a rich set of questions and answer that are useful to a wide audience.  A good question and answer will be found in a Google search, and be helpful for many.  A question that only helps *you* is not useful.  Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the StackOverflow help center.  Thanks!